# A solid strategy to prove: $A \subset B\Leftrightarrow A=A\cap B \Leftrightarrow B= A\cup B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To begin i tried to prove that the first statement implies second, but took a while to type that (now let's prove the other 5 implications, which would fullfill the circle....), I think there must be a short way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no need to prove 5 implications. You want to prove 1) iff 2) iff 3). You can just prove 1) implies 2), 2) implies 3), and 3) implies 1). In general if you want to show that $n$ statements are all equivalent, it is sufficient to prove $n$ implications, i.e. 1) implies 2), 2) implies 3), ..., n) implies 1).

Comment: Very good comment, this should b an answer. If u could add a scource, you know, just to double check I'd be more than happy. :D

Sadly, I believe for this particular excercise it must be an easier way, prove 3 iff 2 doens't seem easy t.t

Comment: The exercise is asking you to prove that the three statements are equivalent. You are going to have to prove at least three implications. There's no way around that.

Comment: But you don't need to prove more than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Statement $1$ is $x\in A\implies x\in B$
>
> Statement $2$ is $x\in A= x\in A\land x\in B$
>
> Statement $3$ is $x\in B = x\in A\lor x\in B$

$1\to2:$ $x\in A\implies x\in B \therefore x\in A\implies x\in A \land x\in B$

$2\to1:$ $x\in A=x\in A \land x\in B\therefore x\in B$

$1\to3:$ $x\in A\implies x\in B \therefore x\in A \lor x\in B \implies x\in B \lor x\in B \implies x\in B$

$3\to1:$ $x\in A \lor x\in B=x\in B\therefore x\in A\implies x\in A \lor x\in B\implies x\in B$

Comment: So clear dude, im selecting this because i think ill even adopt this symbol use for further demo sketches. thx a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

1) Suppose $A \subset B$.  $A \cap B \subset of A$ as intersections are by definition subsets of the intersecting sets.  If $a \in A$ then $a \in B$ as $A \subset B$ $a \in A \cap B$ (because b is in both A and B).  So $ A \subset A \cap B$.  (Because every element of A is in $A \cap B$).  So $A \cap B \subset of A$ and $ A \subset A \cap B$ so $A = A \cap B$.

So 1) => 2.

2) Suppose $A = A \cap B$.  $B \subset A \cup B$ (by definition of union).  Let $b \in A \cup B$.  Then either $b \in A$ or $b \in B$.  If $b \ A = A \cap B$ then $b \in B$.  So all $b \in A \cup B$ is in $B$.  So $A \cup B \subset B$.  So $B = A \cup B$.

So 2) => 3.

3) Suppose $B = A \cup B$.  Suppose $a \in A$.  Then $a \in A \cup B = B$ so $a \in B$.  So every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.  So $A \subset B$.

So 3) => 1.

We're done.

1 => 2.  And 2=>3=>1 so 1 <=> 2.

3 => 1.  And 1=>2=>3 so 1 <=> 3.

2=>3.  And 3=>1=>2 so 2<=> 3.